# Migrate individual identity authentication MVC application to on premise authentication: active directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to migrate an existing MVC application authenticated with individual accounts to be authenticated using Single Sign On with On Premise authentication from our corporate Active Directory.

I have seen several great [walkthroughs](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) for initial setup of On Premise authentication, but no good ones for migrating an existing application. I found this [(Gareth Oakley)](http://www.gazoakley.com/content/migrating-aspnet-mvc-application-adfs-authentication) article, but it does not seem complete.

Do you have any suggestions of articles or instructions about how to migrate an existing application's authentication?
Thank you for your time.